# Finding symbol in text c#

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to retrieve from text one of the symbols like this: "<", "=", "<=", ">", ">=", "<>", "¬=".

Example text might look like `"> 10 dalk tasd ... "` or 
`"      >= 10 asdasdasd .."`. There could be a lot of whitespace characters.

I am trying do something like the below, but it doesn't work:

```
 string sign = new string(textCh.SkipWhile(c => !Char.IsSymbol('>') || !Char.IsSymbol('=') || !Char.IsSymbol('<') || !Char.IsSymbol('¬'))
                                .TakeWhile(c => Char.IsSymbol('=') || Char.IsSymbol('>')).ToArray());
```

How can i retrieve it ?

Comment: I think this task will be much simpler if you use Regex

Comment: the output is just a symbol one of the  "<", "=", "<=", ">", ">=", "<>", "¬="

Comment: do you want the index of all chacters that match the search criteria, or just the first instance?

Comment: @Paweld_00 - is there something possible like `"> 10 dalk tasd > foo => "`?

Comment: >Quote : " I am trying to retrive from text one of the symbols like this " please next time explain better what do you want . You stated in a comment to my answer below that you want to get only one sign that better matches your search pattern and in your question you didn't say a word about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to SkipWhile(criterion OR criterion OR criterion) because a character you want to take can only be one of <, =, or >, and the criteria corresponding to the characters it is *not* will be true and the character will be skipped.

You could change the SkipWhile criteria to be &&, or you could use a Regex.

```
var sign = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("<[>=]?|=|>=?|¬=").Value;
```

Comment: Added specific regex.

Comment: You're right- the trailing [>=] must be optional.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the first such symbol I would use

```
Regex.Match(myString, "<[>=]?|=|>=?|!=").Value
```

Comment: You are missing a few combinations, for example you don't handle `>` by itself. If you fixed it to handle all items the OP listed you would have my upvote

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted- it's really close.  ¬ instead of ! and it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
string example = "avasvasv>asfascvd<hrthtjh";
            int firstIndex = example.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '>', '<', '-', '=' });
            int lastIndex = example.Substring(firstIndex + 1).IndexOfAny(new char[] { '=', '>'});
            string outPutExample = example.Substring(firstIndex + 1).Substring(0, lastIndex); // OutPut -> asfascvd
```